# Code to have Wordpress display a monthly archive?

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, archive, sidebar

We are setting up a WP-MU at work and one of my tasks is to make a link in the sidebar that will go to a page displaying a monthly archive.

The sidebar must not contain the archive list just a link to a page (generated on the fly by WP) that shows the archive by month.

This is probably simple, but I have spent hours going through Codex and blog posts and not making headway.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you,
Frank Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WordPress Codex: Creating an Archive](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index) should explain how to generate the monthly archive page itself.  The template tag to get the monthly archives is:

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
```

If you then have your archives template setup according to [Creating an Archive](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index) you should only need to add a link as so in the sidebar template (i.e. `sidebar.php`):

```
<a href="/archives.php">Monthly Archives</a>
```

with the appropriate URI for your setup.

Comment: Thanks.  That's got me close to what we want.  I had actually tried the above first.  Boss said what we want is for the link to wind up calling archive.php and it to then display a page with links to December 2009, November 2009, October 2009, etc.  If that can be done.